# Http request before launching activity in Android

Tags: android

Every activity in my application requires current user information. Currently I place the loading code in each activity, because every activity can be restored after the application is unloaded from memory.

Is there a way to place the code somewhere where it can be run before any activity created?

Comment: I recommend you check out the [Jetpack Lifecycle API](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to laucnh some code before any activity is created, you should consider implementing your own Application class:

```
package your.package.name

import android.app.Application

class MyApplication: Application(){

    override fun onCreate(){
        super.onCreate()
        fetchCurrentUserData() //fetch current user info from server
    }
}
```

And in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<application
        android:name="your.package.name.MyApplication"
      ...
```

If you want to get rid of constant http requests, consider using singleton that will save the current user data on launch and will provide it for any activity that needs that data.

Comment: This is definitely the answer to may question. But I cannot use onCreate to do http requests. I can launch the request but I cannot wait for it. So any activity can start earlier than I receive the answer from the server. And I do not think that there is a place where it is possible to wait,

Comment: @VitaliyTsirkunov I see. Well, http requests can be long and they never should be running on the main thread, so you should consider that fact while creating your application. As an idea, I can suggest you to start a coroutine using IO scope inside your app class onCreate method, get the http request result and put the resulting data into some singleton that handles that data. And inside your activities you should consider watching this singleton if it contains valid user data, and if it is not, show user some kind of waiting screen or only the part of UI that is working without any user data.